# Total Correlation with Renyi Entropy

Tags: entropy, information-theory, mutual-information

The measure [total correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_correlation) is defined making use of Shannon's entropy:
$$
TC(X_1,\dots,X_m) = \sum_{i} H(X_i) - H(X_1,\dots,X_m)
$$
This comes also with different names: e.g. multi information, or redundancy.

Is there a paper that discusses the generalization of total correlation using the Renyi entropy? Where the Renyi entropy is defined as:
$$
H_{\alpha}(X) = \frac{1}{1-\alpha} log{\sum_x p(x)^{\alpha}}
$$
So far I found that the generalization is possible: [Generalized Redundancies for Time Series Analysis (1995)](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.55.7017). However, no deep insights are discussed in this paper.

Comment: I found out that in the case of two variables this quantity can be negative http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1691274/20197